# Using $(this) inside an if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make an accordion with 3 panels, so when I click on a panel its content should appear and when I click it again its content should disappear

Here is the jquery code

```
jQuery(".item").click(function() {

    if ( jQuery(".content").css("display") == "block" )
    {
        jQuery(this).css("display", "none");
    }

    else if ( jQuery(".content").css("display") == "none" )
    {
        jQuery(this).css("display", "block");
    }
}
```

But the problem here is that **jQuery(this)** here refers to the class **".item"** of course, and the whole panel disappears when clicked.

So I want to refer to **".content"** so that **only** the content of the panel that is being clicked should be displayed or not.

This is the HTML Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div calss="row">
        <div class="accordion">

            <div class="item">
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried this

```
jQuery(".item").click(function() {

    if ( jQuery(".content").css("display") == "block" )
    {
        jQuery(".content").css("display", "none");
    }

    else if ( jQuery(".content").css("display") == "none" )
    {
        jQuery(".content").css("display", "block");
    }
}
```

but then when clicked, the contents of all the 3 panels appear/disapear. Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Share your `html` code.

Comment: It's hard to help without any corresponding HTML Markup. What are the relations between elements with class "item" and elements with class "content" ? Are they nested ? Can you use $(this).find(".content") to find nested element ?

Comment: Sorry for that, I added the HTML code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass `this` in the second argument of `jQuery`, it will find `.content` within `this`. Like so:

```
jQuery(".item").click(function() {

    if ( jQuery(".content", this).css("display") == "block" )
    {
        jQuery(".content", this).css("display", "none");
    }

    else if ( jQuery(".content", this).css("display") == "none" )
    {
        jQuery(".content", this).css("display", "block");
    }
})
```

Your click handler is finding ALL of the elements with the selector, so passing `this` will limit the scope to find the element to hide/show.

To optimize this code, try storing into variables because calling `jQuery`/`$()` can be expensive, especially if you need to access the element several times inside the handler.  You can use the [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function to toggle its state from visible to hidden and vice versa.

```
jQuery(".item").click(function() {

    jQuery(".content", this).toggle();
});
```

Comment: right answer, but the OP is probably better off just using `.toggle` to show and hide the elements...

Comment: ha, you've added the same DRY stuff while I was writing the same in my own answer :p

Comment: Your answer explained better than mine :-)

Comment: It worked thank you, I know I could use the toggle function for the simplicity of code but I didn't know where I should use $(this) so I used the if statement :D but thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery constructor can take a second argument that species the element from which to start the search, therefore you'd use:

```
jQuery('.content', this)
```

this is semantically identical to (but shorter) than:

```
jQuery(this).find('.content')
```

You should consider optimising your code to avoid needless repetition and evaluation of the selector:

```
jQuery('.item').on('click', function() {
    var content = jQuery('.content', this);
    var display = content.css('display');

    if (display === 'block') {
        display = 'none';
    } else if (display === 'none') {
        display = 'block';
    }
    content.css('display', display);
}
```

or better yet, just use the built-in jQuery methods for toggling the visibility of elements and get animated transitions (if you should want them) for free:

```
jQuery('.item').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('.content', this).toggle();
}
```